# Simulated estimate from a linear mixed model with random intercepts

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I wanted to see if there was a quick way to get a bootstrapped parameter estimate and CI using confint() from merTools?

```
library(lme4)
library(merTools)
mod <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1 | Species), data = iris)

confint(mod, level = 0.9, parm = c('(Intercept)','Sepal.Width'),
    method = c("boot"),
    nsim = 500)

                5 %      95 %
(Intercept) 2.3003298 4.5329251
Sepal.Width 0.6423752 0.9790487
```

For example how would I get the mean est for the intercept and Sepal.Width?

Thanks!

Comment: what  do you  mean  by 50% estimate ?

Comment: Stating your problem in a perrspective based on statistics could perhaps attract a clear response.

Comment: Noted, I'm just looking for a bootstrapped mean est. for my model parameters